# How to append data to a dataset in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox

I'm migrating from Fusion Tables to Mapbox. I created a Dataset --> Tileset from an uploaded csv with my data. Formatted my style using the tileset and I can visualize and filter my map using the Mapbox GL JS API, but I'm struggling to understand how to add more entries to my map.
My data is a collection of features with the same properties on each feature, so I display all the features and display the properties based a feature clicked on the map.

If I try to add a feature on Mapbox Studio Dataset, it gives me the option to add a feature, but I have to manually add all the properties for the feature.

Is there a way to append entries or programmatically add data to a dataset to append data to my map?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Mapbox Datasets API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#datasets) to programmatically read, create, update, and remove features from your dataset. For your use case specifically, the [update a dataset endpoint](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#update-a-dataset) and [insert or update a feature endpoint](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#insert-or-update-a-feature) will likely be useful.

Note that after you update your dataset, you will need to re-export it as a tileset to then use the updated data in your map style.

Alternatively, you could consider using the new [Mapbox Tilesets API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#tilesets), which provides a powerful pipeline for programmatically creating and updating tilesets. [This tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/get-started-tilesets-api-and-cli/) is a useful resource for getting started with the Tilesets API and Tilesets CLI.